# Different CSS based on URL

Tags: javascript, css, url

I have to domains with the same name, one ending with `.nl` and one with `.be`. For example `domain.nl` and `domain.be`. They follow both the same general styling, but I wan't some elements have a different styling based on if it is `.nl` and `.be`. How can I achieve this without loading in additional css files?

Comment: Serve up a different stylesheet on both (the common parts can be in a separate file). Or serve up different HTML, for example with a `class="domain-nl"` or `class="domain-be"` on the body. Or if you hate your users, use JavaScript to check the URL domain and dynamically load a style sheet ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using plain Javascript, I'd suggest creating different CSS files for domains; adding just the differences in 2 different files, one for `be` and one for `nl`.

`somefilename_be.css`

```
{
    body: 'green';
}
```

`somefilename_nl.css`

```
{
    body: 'red';
}
```

All same styling should go in a common file like `common.css`.

Then you can load CSS file conditionally based on the domain.

```
if (window.location.host.split('.')[1] === "be")
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="somefilename_be.css" />');
else 
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="somefilename_nl.css" />');
```

**Using JS Frameworks (React, Angular, Vue, Next, Svelte)**

```
if (window.location.host.split('.')[1] === "be")
    import('somefilename_be.css'));    
else 
    import('somefilename_nl.css'));
```

Comment: you can additonal differences of CSS in additonal files, that will work

Comment: I wan't to do it with Javascript and without loading in additional files. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks, but it is not so handy because the differents in the styling will be minimal, so it is really necasarry **not** to make two different stylesheets for small differentses

Comment: CSS itself is not aware of the URL of the page, so it is not possible with only CSS - you need some script either on server side or client side. I suggest referring to different classes of some high-level element and set the proper class with JavaScript.

Comment: @Noam Thanks, how can you check the url for that?

Comment: The same way as in the answer we are now commenting on. But alright it's better that I'll form it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the differences are small, you can rely on a class on the root element, controlled with JavaScript. For example:

```js
if (/\.be$/.test(window.location.host)) {
  document.documentElement.classList.add('variant-be');
}
```

```css
.variant-text {
  background: yellow;
}

.variant-be .variant-text {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="variant-text">A text with two possible backgrounds</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But what does that first part in the `if`-statement mean? (/\.be$/)

Comment: It's a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) matching a string that ends with ".be". It's not the only way to analyze the string but it's a useful one.

Comment: Convienent if its just one class to add. Likely to get dirty if I have multiple elements to add classes.

Comment: @sid you can make as many changes as you wish depend on a single class. You only need additional classes if you have additional conditions.

Comment: @Noam Thanks for the help. I have combined Sid's solution with yours and now m problem is solved!